# Creating an editable Text Field with JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have trouble creating an editable text field with `JavaScript`, I found some function to edit but I don´t understand if it is possible to edit the title from **High School** to **Middle School** which is created by the function `createTextNode`

My doubt is particularly in using the instruction `addEvent(document.getElementById("h1"), "click", new Function("edit(this)"));` for adding event to edit the text field, run code snippets to see the result

[try the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phfuLjab/4/)

```js
var school = new School(1);

function School(id) {
  this.id = id;
  Unload_School();

  function Unload_School() {

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "school";

    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.id = "h1";
    h1.style.color = "red";

    var title = document.createTextNode("High School");
    h1.appendChild(title);

    // I use here but not work
    addEvent(document.getElementById("h1"), "click", new Function("edit(this)"));

    var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.style.color = "blue";

    var subtitle = document.createTextNode("List Of Students:");
    h3.appendChild(subtitle);

    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(h3);

    document.body.appendChild(div);
  };
}

function addEvent(obj, evType, fn) {
  try {
    obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
  } catch (e) {}
  try {
    obj.attachEvent("on" + evType, fn);
  } catch (e) {}
}

function edit(param) {
  var elem = param;
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("value", elem.firstChild.nodeValue);
  removeChildren(elem);
  elem.appendChild(input);
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  addEvent(input, "blur", function() {
    removeChildren(elem);
    elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  });
}

function removeChildren(param) {
  for (var i = 0, elem; elem = param.childNodes[i]; i++) {
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
}
```

```css
#school {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

#h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans - serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>High School</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="school"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.title="Whatever Title You Want To Put";` However I do not get exactly what you are asking for. Post a working fiddle if possible

Comment: @avck, try this https://jsfiddle.net/phfuLjab/1/

Comment: @avck, in `h1.id = "h1";`  **High School**, I wanna change to **Middle School**, I create an title `var title = document.createTextNode("High School");` and add to `h1.appendChild(title);` and I wanna use `addEvent(document.getElementById("h1"), "click", new Function("edit(this)"));`to edit the **title** to **new title** inside **h1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: When creating elements, do not look for element before you have appended it to DOM.

[check this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phfuLjab/3/)

```
 div.appendChild(h1);
 div.appendChild(h3);
 document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Only after appending all the elements you should search for your element.

```
 addEvent(document.getElementById("h1"), "click", new Function("edit(this)"));
```

Comment: thanks it´s work, now I understand, Only after appending all the elements you should search for your element.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code from `addEvent(getElementById("h1"), "click", new Function("edit(this)"));` to `addEvent(document.getElementById("h1"), "click", new Function("edit(this)"));`. Also there is no ID called `h1`.

Comment: there is an id called h1, he is creating it if you look